# Deserialize JSON that might be an integer or a list of strings in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am using `C#` to deserialize a collection of JSON strings. Each string has a property `employer_normalized` that is supposed to contain a `string` and `List<int>` where the values in the `List` are always positive. In some cases `employer_normalized` is set to `-1`, so I want to override these cases with some behavior that sets `employer_normalized` to `null`.

Here is my class:

```
public class EmployerNormalized
{
  public string company;
  public List<int> code;
}
```

**Good JSON**

```
"employer_normalized": {
        "company": "self",
        "code": [
          "4581 ",
          "6732 ",
          "9121",
          "9999 ",
          "5947 ",
          "8322 ",
          "8351 ",
          "7335 ",
          "9999 ",
          "4225 ",
          "8399 "
        ]
      }
```

**Bad JSON**

```
"employer_normalized": -1
```

I am currently using `Json.NET` to do my JSON parsing. What is an elegant solution to solving this problem? Is it best to just set the `employer_normalized` value to `null` if it is `-1`? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Fire whoever developed the application that generates this JSON :)

Comment: I wish I could. I'm stuck with this for now, though, so I've got to figure out a way to handle those specific instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom JsonConverter to deal with this situation.  Wherever you are expecting a `EmployerNormalized`, the converter can check whether the value of that property is `-1` and return null, otherwise deserialize it normally.

Here is the code for the converter:

```
public class EmployerNormalizedConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(EmployerNormalized));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            return token.ToObject<EmployerNormalized>();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here is a demo showing how to use it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""good"" : {
                ""company"": ""self"",
                ""code"": [
                    ""4581 "",
                    ""6732 "",
                    ""9121"",
                    ""9999 "",
                    ""5947 "",
                    ""8322 "",
                    ""8351 "",
                    ""7335 "",
                    ""9999 "",
                    ""4225 "",
                    ""8399 ""
                ]
            },
            ""bad"" : -1
        }";

        Wrapper wrapper =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(json, 
                new EmployerNormalizedConverter());

        DumpEmployer("good", wrapper.good);
        DumpEmployer("bad", wrapper.bad);
    }

    private static void DumpEmployer(string prop, EmployerNormalized emp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop);
        if (emp != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  company: " + emp.company);
            Console.WriteLine("  codes: " + 
                string.Join(", ", emp.code.Select(c => c.ToString())));
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("  (null)");
    }

    public class Wrapper
    {
        public EmployerNormalized good { get; set; }
        public EmployerNormalized bad { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployerNormalized
    {
        public string company;
        public List<int> code;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
good
  company: self
  codes: 4581, 6732, 9121, 9999, 5947, 8322, 8351, 7335, 9999, 4225, 8399
bad
  (null)
```

**Important note:** You might be tempted to decorate the `EmployerNormalized` class with `[JsonConverter(typeof(EmployerNormalizedConverter))]`, but if you do that, then the converter, in its current form, will end up calling itself recursively until it errors out with a `StackOverflowException`.  If you need/want to use the attribute, then the code of the `ReadJson` method in the converter will need to be changed so that it manually creates an instance of the `EmployerNormalized` class and populates all of its properties individually rather than calling `token.ToObject<EmployerNormalized>()`.  Here is an alternate version of `ReadJson` that will avoid the recursion problem:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
    if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        EmployerNormalized employer = new EmployerNormalized();
        employer.company = token["company"].ToString();
        employer.code = token["code"].ToObject<List<int>>();
        return employer;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Any idea why I might be getting this error? `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll`. I am dealing with a list of objects that contain an `EmployerNormalized` object.

Comment: Are you using a `JsonConverter` attribute on the `EmployerNormalized` class?  If so, that will result in the converter calling itself recursively.

Answer (score 1):

I know this sucks, but you can first try to parse the `JSON string` to an `Object` with the structure of your **Good JSON**, and in case of parsing error, parse to the second case (**Bad JSON**).

Comment: So you mean I should create a class that represents the bad JSON and parse to that in the case of an exception?

Comment: Pretty much it - *awkward*

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to just set `employer_normalized` to `null`, but I just need to make note of that because I plan on inserting these records into a database. My DB will scream if I insert a `null` value into a non-nullable field. Ugh!

Comment: Can't you just check if the string is `"employer_normalized": -1` and then do that? I believe you should just check the business rules for that.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant - only set it to `null` in the event that it is `"-1"`. There's no other way to interpret that value. I updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: Do you need to serialize this same objects to a string json again?

Comment: No. I need them to insert them into a database, though.

Comment: The problem is, `employer_normalized` is nested within yet a larger JSON object. As such, I can't just skip these entries. They must be set to some value, hence I consider `null`.

Comment: Have you consider then just adding the `[]` brackets to turn the Bad json into the Good json? You can do it with some simple regex.

Comment: So you mean I should rewrite the file using RegEx's so I can more easily parse it?

Comment: Something like that. For example, this regex - `\"employer_normalized"\:.*\"code\": \[.*\]` checks the conformity of the json string (if it's a good json). If it's not, you could just insert the `[]` brackets, via regex also. This way, you will have the `code` field as an array with the `-1` only value.

Comment: Good thought. I accepted the answer below because it is a cleaner solution, I think. Thank you for your help though!